# Why does my Image not load in this path, but in another?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, embedded-resource

I Tried putting an image onto a JButton. After wrote down the path to the image, ran the Program,then image was not on the Button. Code Sample below:

```
public static JButton start = new JButton(new ImageIcon("resources//img//menu//Start_Game.png"));
```

The "resources" folder is in the "src" folder. [Here is the Hirarchy in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWLAi.png)

After I double checked I spelled everything right, I put in an other path.

```
public static JButton start = new JButton(new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//Tindir//Hauptmenue//Start_Game.png"));
```

Suddenly it worked. It is obvious that the first path was not correct.

**Question** If there is a way to input a path to an Image in the same Project-Folder as the Code?

Comment: You put the resources folder under the top project level, and use "/menu/item.png" or "/game/item.png" to access images in a menu or game subfolder, respectively.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not that way - those arguments are *filenames*, and java code is not deployed as a sack of files. It's deployed as a jar file. **An entry inside a jar file does not count** and can *never* be used with this API.

So, don't use this call. Use the other one, that takes a URL, because you certainly *can* represent either a file, or an entry within a jarfile, as one of those:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("Start_Game.png")
```

That is what you put instead of `"resources/etc/Start_Game.png"` in that code. This looks for a resource named `Start_Game.png` in the exact same place that `MyApp.class` is found, even if that is found inside a jar file, loaded out of a DB, live-streamed from the internet - whatever. You're using the same mechanism.

If your Start-Game file is somewhere else, start with a `/`. It seems like you want `/img/menu/Start_Game.png` here.

This trick is an easy way to get an idea of what you're doing:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class"));
    }
}
```

and you'll figure it out with that output.